# print + each() block - why does joining not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

I'm expecting this output:

```
output:xyz
```

But if I type the following:

```
a = ["x", "y", "z"]
print "output:" + a.each {|i| print i}.to_s
```

Why do I get an 'xyz' before the word output as well as after it?

```
xyzoutput:xyz
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In irb:

```
>> %w{x y z}.each {|i| i }
=> ["x", "y", "z"]
```

The return value of a call to `each` is the `Enumerable` object that it was called on.  So you're basically printing out each element of the array in the block you're passing to `each`, and then converting the array to a string and printing it again, having concatenated it with the the string `"output:"`.

Answer (score 1):

probably what you want here is:

```
puts "output: #{a.join}"
```

or, more verbosely, in case the idea is clearer this way:

```
puts "output: #{a.map {|element| element.to_s}.join}"
```